# ProGuard error can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.entity

Tags: android, proguard

I get always with ProGuard following error:

```
[2012-05-19 17:50:13 - xxx] Warning: there were 13 unresolved references to      program class members.
[2012-05-19 17:50:13 - xxx]          Your input classes appear to be     inconsistent.
[2012-05-19 17:50:13 - xxx]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2012-05-19 17:50:13 - xxx]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2012-05-19 17:50:13 - xxx]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2012-05-19 17:50:13 - xxx] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2012-05-19 17:55:40 - xxx] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2012-05-19 17:55:40 - xxx] Note: there were 239 duplicate class definitions.
[2012-05-19 17:55:40 - xxx] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart:    can't find superclass or interface org.apache.james.mime4j.message.BodyPart
[2012-05-19 17:55:40 - xxx] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.james.mime4j.message.Multipart
[2012-05-19 17:55:40 - xxx] Warning: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MinimalField: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.james.mime4j.parser.Field
```

My proguard.cfg file is:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable

-libraryjars /libs/crittercism_v2_0_1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.2.2.jar
-libraryjars /libs/FlurryAgent.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpmime-4.0.3.jar
-libraryjars /libs/json_simple-1.1.jar
```

I've already added all my external libs so why am I getting always these errors?
Can anybody help?

**EDIT 21.05.2012:**
The problem is if you add "Dropbox" jar AND "ActionBarSherlock".
If I add only "Dropbox", I have no problem.
If I add only "ActionBarSherlock", I have no problem.
But if I added both, I would get the errors above.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem exists if you have added "ActionBarSherlock" and "DropBox" jars to your project.
To solve the problem, add the below line to your proguard-project.txt file:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.**
```

The warning will be ignored and it will work because each of the jars alone are working.
So I think, this will be the bug in ProGuard, if both are added.

Comment: it's not work and the error is: Warning:a.a$a: can't find referenced field 'org.apache.http.HttpEntity wrappedEntity' in program class a.a$a

Comment: @Kenji: Sorry I am not using ActionBarSherlock anymore, so I can't help you out.

Comment: @BinilS: What do you mean with "API will not call by using org.apache"?

Answer (score 10):

Possibly you need to :

> -keep class org.apache.http.**
>
> -keep interface org.apache.http.**

That is assuming of course ProGuard is complaining about the apache classes. Admittedly I am guessing somewhat as I'm no expert on ProGuard.

Comment: Yes i think this is a solution, but i don't want to keep it because i don't use it. And all external jars i have added to libraryjars! So why i am getting this error?

Comment: You may not have a choice. Does looking on the ProGuard example page help? http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html

Comment: This does not solve the issue - use @chrisonline above.

Comment: Mine may indeed be the incorrect answer but switching off a warning isn't a good idea either, you're just hiding the problem I believe. Further investigation into the problem to understand it is required.