# Proguard, HttpClient and SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: android, maven, proguard, android-proguard

I want to use ProGuard in my app. I use org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient to send requests to the server.
Without Proguard it works good, but when I turn on the ProGuard I can build the app, but in run-time when I run the app I received the following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException No peer certificate
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java146)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java93)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java388)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java360)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java555)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java465)
    at com.newrelic.agent.android.instrumentation.HttpInstrumentation.execute(HttpInstrumentation.java165)
    at com.abc.communication.CommunicationManager.sendRequest(CommunicationManager.java765)
    at com.abc.communication.CommunicationManager.sendPingRequest(CommunicationManager.java616)
    at com.abc.communication.CommunicationManager.access$100(CommunicationManager.java94)
    at com.abc.communication.CommunicationManager$1.run(CommunicationManager.java190)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java841)
```

I can't understand where the problem. I disabled shrink and optimization, but it not helped. Also I tried to enable shrink option only, i.e. obfuscation and optimization were disabled, but it not helped too.

To build my app I use maven. Part of my pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <configuration>
        <release>true</release>
        <sdk>
            <platform>22</platform>
        </sdk>
        <undeployBeforeDeploy>false</undeployBeforeDeploy>

        ...

        <proguard>
            <skip>false</skip>
            <config>proguard.cfg</config>
            <configs>
                <config>proguard-android.txt</config>
            </configs>
            <outputDirectory>proguard-files</outputDirectory>
            <filterMavenDescriptor>true</filterMavenDescriptor>
            <filterManifest>true</filterManifest>
        </proguard>
    </configuration>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

proguard-android.txt is standard file from the SDK folder

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

My proguard.cfg file:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity

-keep public class * extends android.app.Application

-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keep class com.newrelic.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.newrelic.**
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses

-keep public class javax.net.ssl.**
-keepclassmembers public class javax.net.ssl.** { *; }

-keep class org.spongycastle.* { *; }
-dontwarn org.spongycastle.*

-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers public class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-keep class com.abc.communication.CommunicationManager { *; }
-keep class com.abc.communication.CommunicationManager$* { *; }

-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
```

Comment: Compare the two created APKs (with/without ProGuard) using apktool Decompile both APK files and then use a file comparison tool to detect the changes.

Comment: This link may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666769/proguard-error-cant-find-superclass-or-interface-org-apache-http-entity

Comment: @Robert I don't understand how can I compare these files, because they are different files. First file is original and second one is obfuscated.

Comment: @floyd I think I used these instructions to say to ProGuard "don't touch third party libs". I think the problem is that I used new version of apache http lib in the code. After ProGuard something goes wrong. I will write the simple app with http and run obfuscate with/without new apache lib. Thanks guys for your help. I will write here my results.

Comment: @yugico The one APK works, the other does not work. If you want to find out what is going wrong you have to know the differences. Usually ProGuard does not affect SSL/TLS trusted certificates, therefore you have to find out what is going wrong. BTW: Both versions are release versions (not debug versions)? Some libraries disable certificate checking in debug builds.

Comment: Consolidate the 2 config files mentioned in "proguard.config " tags

Comment: @Robert both versions are release versions.

Comment: @RobertRowntree I made the consolidation of the 2 files, but it didn't help

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that in lines:

```
-keep class org.spongycastle.* { *; }
-dontwarn org.spongycastle.*
```

I used *****. It's wrong. You must use ******.

* means "don't touch all classes in this package"
** means "don't touch all classes in the package and all sub-packages"

Thanks to all.