# How to find which library is using a missing class and causing Proguard errors?

Tags: android, proguard, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-6.0-marshmallow

Now that Android M has completely removed the Apache HTTP client, I'm finding that some of the libraries I use still depend on or reference it, so while Proguarding, I'm getting errors like:

`Warning:org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.HttpEntity`

[this question/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666769/proguard-error-cant-find-superclass-or-interface-org-apache-http-entity) recommends using `-dontwarn` to suppress the errors and this does allow it build, but I'd rather understand what is using that so I can avoid runtime errors. I can't find references to those classes in my own code, so it must be in libraries. Proguard doesn't give any info on where it saw this class.

Is there a way to better understand where is error is coming from?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the JarAnalyzer? (http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer)

I'm not 100% sure it works on android JARs, but I'm trying to find a windows machine to test it out right now.

I also found JDepend (http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html), still trying to get that one to run as well.